# Anaconda Python2.7 compiling packages error on Windows 7

Tags: c++, python-2.7

Try install ,pip install spacy
Also made conda install mingw

> D:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts>gcc -v
>   Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=D:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat....\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/programms/anaconda2/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/lto-wrapper.exe
>   Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   Configured with: ../../../build/gcc/src/configure --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/c/bb/vista64-mingw32/mingw-x86-x86_64/build/build/ro
>   ot --with-sysroot=/c/bb/vista64-mingw32/mingw-x86-x86_64/build/build/root --enable-languages=all,obj-c++ --enable-fully-dynamic-string --dis
>   able-multilib
>   Thread model: win32
>   gcc version 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental) (GCC)

Got Error. Lock like MinGW and Visual C++ mixed

> d:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-b
>   uild-pgrnrn\spacy\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\spacy\include\msvc9 -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Id:\prog
>   ramms\anaconda2\PC -c spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\spacy\parts_of_speech.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-
>   unused-function
>     cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp: In function 'void __Pyx_RaiseTooManyValuesError(Py_ssize_t)':
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp:1947:94: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp:1947:94: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp: In function 'void __Pyx_RaiseNeedMoreValuesError(Py_ssize_t)':
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp:1953:48: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp:1953:48: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 3 has type 'Py_ssize_t {aka long lo
>   ng int}' [-Wformat]
>     spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp:1953:48: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>     writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\spacy\parts_of_speech.def
>     d:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\g++.bat -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\spacy\parts_of_speech.o build\temp.win-amd64
>   -2.7\Release\spacy\parts_of_speech.def -Ld:\programms\anaconda2\libs -Ld:\programms\anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 -Ld:\programms\anaconda2\PC\VS9.
>   0\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\spacy\parts_of_speech.pyd
>     building 'spacy.strings' extension
>     d:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-b
>   uild-pgrnrn\spacy\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\spacy\include\msvc9 -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Id:\prog
>   ramms\anaconda2\PC -c spacy/strings.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\spacy\strings.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
>     cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
>     In file included from spacy/strings.cpp:248:0:
>     c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\spacy\include\msvc9/stdint.h:34:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!"
>     In file included from c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\spacy\include/murmurhash/MurmurHash3.h:8:0,
>     cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option '-Wno-strict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
>     In file included from thinc/linalg.cpp:248:0:
>     c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\thinc\include\msvc9/stdint.h:34:2: error: #error "Use this header only with Microsoft Vi
>   sual C++ compilers!"
>         error: command 'd:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 
>         Failed building wheel for thinc
>         Running setup.py clean for thinc
>         Failed to build spacy thinc
>         Installing collected packages: thinc, pathlib, semver, sputnik, ujson,      spacy

List of all output i skipped

> Running setup.py install for thinc ... error
>       Complete output from command d:\programms\anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\runa\appdata\lo
>   cal\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\thinc\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec
>   (compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-hhhilf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-e
>   xternally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       running build_ext
>       building 'thinc.linalg' extension
>       d:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip
>   -build-pgrnrn\thinc\include -Ic:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\thinc\include\msvc9 -Id:\programms\anaconda2\include -Id:\pr
>   ogramms\anaconda2\PC -c thinc/linalg.cpp -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\thinc\linalg.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
>   -msse3
>
> gcc.exe: error: thinc/linalg.cpp: No such file or directory
>       gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>       compilation terminated.
>       error: command 'd:\Programms\Anaconda2\Scripts\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
>   Command "d:\programms\anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgr
>   nrn\thinc\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**,
>    'exec'))" install --record c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-hhhilf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --comp
>   ile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pgrnrn\thinc\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
#error "Use this header only with Microsoft Visual C++ compilers!" In file included from c:\users\runa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-...
```

Spacy expects to be compiled with VC++ on Windows and incorrectly includes a custom version of stdint.h designed to work around problems with VC++.

Specifically in setup.py (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/3431e7b86feabdba014c2200692677872cd8f595/setup.py) it calls new_compiler().compiler_type == 'msvc' to check the compiler type on Windows. However according to the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html) this will always return 'msvc' on Windows.

Probably the easiest solution is to install Visual Studio Express and use VC++ to compile on Windows. You might also consider reporting a bug.

Comment: Yes, you was right, I install visual studio express 2015 , and it's starts to work.